# Finding element by value Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I got another problem by finding the correct element for a radio button.
We got two buttons, one for Visa and one for MasterCard. They are build identically, except for the value.
[image]

I tried:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type= 'radio'][@value='V']"))).click()
```

or different combinations from these attributes.
There isn't a frame or something like that. Acutally, I should be inside the scope.

Comment: Are you getting any error when you click on the radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following for visa:

```
//img[contains(@src,'visa.svg')]/..
```

The same for mastercard:

```
//img[contains(@src,'mastercard.svg')]/..
```

or

```
//img[contains(@src,'visa.svg')]/../../label
//img[contains(@src,'mastercard.svg')]/../../label
```

Both should work

Comment: Wow nice! It worked. Thank you so much. But what does `/../../` this mean? Never seen this kind of syntax in combination with Xpath.

Comment: `/..` to go to parent from current node

Comment: Or in other words "Go level Up"